# How to load a dynamic view css file using requireJs & Backbone

Tags: javascript, css, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I need that each view will load it's own css file when navigate to the view.
currently the css file have been loaded ( I can see it loaded on the network section) but it's not effect the page style

any idea ?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'text!../templates/Login.html',
    'text!../css/styleshet.css'
], function($, html, css){      

});
```

Comment: I guess it is not added to page, you just 'download' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you need to add it to your page manually...
the fixed is :

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'text!../templates/Login.html',
    'text!../css/styleshet.css'
], function($, html, css){      

//this will remove the old view css 
if ($("#customCss").length > 0)
            $("#customCss").empty();

//this will add the current css to the page 
 $('head').append('<style type="text/css" id="customCss"> ' + css + '</style>');

});
```

Thanks to [Radek Michna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301788/radek-michna)

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.js` (the file described in `data-main` atribute of **requirejs** **script tag**):

```
(function(){        
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: 'ASSETS',
        paths: {
            YOURJS: 'PATH/TO/JS/YOURJS'
        },
        shim: {
            "YOURJS": {
                "deps": ['css!PATH/TO/CSS/YOURCSS']
            },
        }
    });
})();
```

Create `css.js` file in the same directory `baseUrl` option:

```
define({
    load: function (url, req, onLoad, config) {
        var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        //link.id   = ;
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = config.baseUrl+url+'.css';
        link.media = 'all';
        head.appendChild(link); 
        onLoad();                       
    }       
});
```